# Method not seen when called from a 2d array of objects (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm making a minesweeper game in java, and I have declared a 2d array of Tile objects as the game board. 2d array `board` is declared as an instance variable, then filled with Tile objects once the user passes a size (4x4 to 10x10, inclusive). I then attempt to call a method on a specific object from another method in class `GameBoard` using the format `board[a][b].setMarked(true)`. I receive the error "cannot find symbol - method setMarked(boolean)". I'm confused as to how GameBoard cannot see the method in Tile, since it was declared as public and I can call it from a non-array object. I'm assuming it has to do with the instance variables and constructors?

GameBoard class relevant code:

```
public class GameBoard {
    private Object[][] board;

    public GameBoard(int a) {
        board = new Object[a][a];
        for (int i=0; i<a; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<a; j++) {
                board[i][j] = new Tile(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void mark(int a,int b) {
        board[a][b].setMarked(true);
    }
}
```

Tile class relevant code:

```
public void setMarked(boolean m) {
    marked = m;
}
```

where `marked` is a boolean instance variable declared in Tile.

Comment: I thought so too, and tried it with no luck

Answer (score 1):

You have array of objects, and Object have no method setMarked(boolean m), think about changing it to array of Tiles

Comment: Thanks, I kinda thought it would be something that easy.